# How can I add more floating sub-sections to a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview, sections

My goal is to represent a tree hierarchy much like this:

```
Building
  Zone
    Floor
      Room
```

... using a table view.

To accomplish this the design asks for each tree level to be embedded as its own `Section`.

A `.plain UITableView` is limited as it supports only ***one*** floating Section.  Further research led me to create my own custom `SectionView`, and placed it just below the navbar.

I've also strategized with marking certain `rows` as my *fake sections* and playing with `scrollViewDidScroll` also seems like the correct direction.

But am now perplexed in how to accomplish tracking the location of certain *section* cells, stacking them to float accordingly and animate scrolling correctly through each level section overlap.

To clarify, in my example below, the scrolling should stack like this:

```
Building <section>
Zone(s)  <sub-section>
Floor(s) <sub-section>
 Room(s) <rows>
```

[image]

Other tree formats also need to be supported:

```
Building <section>
  Zone 1 <section>
    Room <rows>
  Zone 2 <section>
    Room <rows> 


Building <section>
    Room <rows>
```

So the tree structure isn't fixed.